# Tkinter Clock causing window crash

Tags: python-3.x, time, tkinter, clock

The clock in my tkinter window is causing the entire window to crash. I know this because it works flawlessly when I comment it out. Is there any way I can adjust or restructure the code to prevent crashes? The crashes typically occur 5-10 seconds into the runtime.

Below is the entire program

The clock/ date variables and update_clock() function are what is in question.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time


def dateconverter():
    global today
    if today[0].lower() == '0' and today[1].lower() == '1':
        today = 'January'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '0' and today[1].lower() == '2':
        today = 'February'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '0' and today[1].lower() == '3':
        today = 'March'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '0' and today[1].lower() == '4':
        today = 'April'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '0' and today[1].lower() == '5':
        today = 'May'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '0' and today[1].lower() == '6':
        today = 'June'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '0' and today[1].lower() == '7':
        today = 'July'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '0' and today[1].lower() == '8':
        today = 'August'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '0' and today[1].lower() == '9':
        today = 'September'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '1' and today[1].lower() == '0':
        today = 'October'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '1' and today[1].lower() == '1':
        today = 'November'+' '+time.strftime("%d")
    if today[0].lower() == '1' and today[1].lower() == '2':
        today = 'December'+' '+time.strftime("%d")

    return today

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('Car Display')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        load = Image.open('/Users/jakeglunk/Desktop/928BG_Vert.png')
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=-2,y=-2)
        batteryimg = ''
        battery = Label(self, image=batteryimg, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, width = 0)
        battery.image = batteryimg
        battery.place(x=1000,y=30)
        global percentage
        percentage = 12
        battlevel = Label(self, text=str(percentage)+'%', bg='#242424', font= ("System",40), fg='white')
        battlevel.place(x=900,y=35)

    def battery_window():
        battwindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
        load2 = Image.open('/Users/jakeglunk/Desktop/928Battery_Vert.png')
        render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load2)
        img2 = Label(battwindow, image=render2)
        img2.image = render2
        img2.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        battwindow.geometry('1080x1920')
        battwindow.overrideredirect(1)

    def motor_window():
        battwindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
        load2 = Image.open('/Users/jakeglunk/Desktop/928Motor_Vert.png')
        render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load2)
        img2 = Label(battwindow, image=render2)
        img2.image = render2
        img2.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        battwindow.geometry('1080x1920')
        battwindow.overrideredirect(1)

    clock = Label(self, text='time', bg='#242424', font = ("System", 55), fg='white')
    clock.place(x=2,y=0)
    date = Label(self, text= 'date', bg= '#242424', font = ("System", 40), fg='white')
    date.place(x=2,y=65)

    battbuttimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('/Users/jakeglunk/Desktop/BattButtx264.png'))
    battbutton = Button(self, image=battbuttimg, bg = '#4d4d4d',command=battery_window)
    battbutton.image = battbuttimg
    battbutton.place(x=408,y=305)

    batttext = Label(self, text='Battery', bg='#4d4d4d', font = ("System", 50), fg='white')
    batttext.place(x=458,y=585)

    mapbuttimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('/Users/jakeglunk/Desktop/Mapsx264.png'))
    mapsbutt =  Button(self, image=mapbuttimg)
    mapsbutt.image = mapbuttimg
    mapsbutt.place(x=72,y=305)

    mapstext = Label(self, text='Maps', bg='#4d4d4d', font = ("System", 50), fg='white')
    mapstext.place(x=140,y=585)

    motorbuttimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('/Users/jakeglunk/Desktop/MotorButtx264.png'))
    motorbutt = Button(self, image=motorbuttimg, command=motor_window)
    motorbutt.image = motorbuttimg
    motorbutt.place(x=744,y=305)

    motortext = Label(self, text='Motor', bg='#4d4d4d', font = ("System", 50), fg='white')
    motortext.place(x=810,y=585)


    def update_clock():
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M")
        clock.configure(text=now)
        clock.after(1000, update_clock)
        global today
        today = time.strftime("%m/%d")
        dateconverter()
        date.configure(text=today)
        date.after(1000, update_clock)
    update_clock()

    def batterymeter():
        global percentage
        lowbattery = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('/Users/jakeglunk/Desktop/LowBatt.png'))
        halfbattery = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('/Users/jakeglunk/Desktop/HalfBatt.png'))
        mediumbattery = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('/Users/jakeglunk/Desktop/MedBatt.png'))
        fullbattery = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('/Users/jakeglunk/Desktop/FullBatt.png'))
        if percentage <= 25:
            battery.configure(image=lowbattery)
            battery.image = lowbattery
        if percentage <= 50 and percentage > 25:
            battery.configure(image=halfbattery)
            battery.image = halfbattery
        if percentage <= 75 and percentage > 50:
            battery.configure(image=mediumbattery)
            battery.image = mediumbattery
        if percentage > 75:
            battery.configure(image=fullbattery)
            battery.image = fullbattery
        battery.after(1000, batterymeter)
    batterymeter()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('1080x1920')
root.overrideredirect(1)
app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the only problem, but one problem is that you're calling `update_clock` twice from `update_clock`. You call it once, and it adds two jobs to the "after" queue. One job comes off when it runs, and it adds two more. Now there are three. The next one comes off and adds two more, so there are four. One comes off but you add two more so there are five, and so on and so on, and then happens twice a second.